# Camera Intent: why data coming null?

Tags: android

I need create a directory and save images there, so I tried a lot of things and I found this tutorial at google page: [Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

So, I did this:

```
openCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });


rivate void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.apps.cadcom.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Util.REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    }

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

In the manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.apps.cadcom.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

provider_path.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.apps.cadcom/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

I have not changed anything, this is exactly the same code that is in the tutorial. So I'm confused. When the `onActivityResult` method is calling, the variable `data` comes as null, but `resultCode` comes as -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the onActivityResult method is calling, the variable data comes as null

That is because it is supposed to be `null`. There is not supposed to be any output delivered via `onActivityResult()`, other than the result code.

You know where the photo is supposed to be. It is supposed to be in `photoFile`. That is where you asked the camera app to put the photo, via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. So, look for it there first. Then, if the photo is not there, see if it was a buggy camera app and returned a `Uri` via the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Thanks! I would stay the rest of my life trying to fix this